# Visual Studio ribbon designer - make button larger?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, ribbon

I'm trying to make an Outlook 2010 add-in, but I can't get the ribbon customization correct.  My button will not resize.  I'd like it to take up as much space as possible within the group, like a normal button.  Here's what I'm stuck with, and I have no idea how to resize it:

[image]

How do I resize the button (button1) so it's larger?